# Sharing non iTunes music on family sharing

Tags: itunes, apple-id

my question is can you share music from you iTunes library if you put it on there from a CD. We have a lot of CD's at home and on my parents computer and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only locally with Home Sharing.

Apple [states](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203046) that with Family Sharing activated, you can share

> Music, movies, and TV shows from the iTunes Store.

but you can't share

> Songs added to iTunes Match from outside the iTunes Store.

---

For Home Sharing:

You have to rip all your cd's first.
Then open iTunes and turn on Home Sharing.

From [Apple's Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202190):

> 1. Open iTunes and make sure you have the latest version.
> 2. Go to File > Home Sharing > Turn on Home Sharing.
> 3. Enter your Apple ID and password. Make sure to use the same Apple ID when you set up Home Sharing on your other devices.
> 4. Repeat these steps on other computers that you want to use with Home Sharing

This will only work with iTunes, Apple TV's and iDevices on the same network, and the sharing computer must be turned on.